# How can I style padding and border of a plot from plain css

Tags: css, plotly, transcrypt

I have a number of inline-block divs with plots in them. For now I connect them all to separate instances of the same plot, but they will be distinct in the end.

When I try to style them, e.g.

```
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid gray;
```

Plotly comes up with a double border and ignores my padding.

[image]

Of course I could wrap the plotly divs in outer divs and style those,
but surely there must be a way to make plotly divs, meaning divs with an id that is picked up by Plotly.plot, obey general CSS rather than do their own thing?

I am using the [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org) Python to JavaScript compiler and the plain plotly.js library, without any of the remote stuff. Code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                display: inline-block;
                overflow: hidden;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 10;
                width: 500;
                height: 500;
                border: 1px solid gray;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="lin"></div>
        <div id="log"></div>
        <div id="polar"></div>
        <div id="ribbon"></div>
        <div id="wireframe"></div>
        <div id="surface"></div>
        <div id="bar"></div>
        <div id="pie"></div>
        <div id="gant"></div>

        <script src="__javascript__/plotly_demo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Python:

```
__pragma__ ('jskeys')   # For convenience, allow JS style unquoted string literals as dictionary keys

import numscrypt
import math

xValues = [2 * math.pi * step / 200 for step in range (201)]
yValues = [math.sin (xValue) + 0.5 * math.sin (xValue * 3 + 0.25 * math.sin (xValue * 5)) for xValue in xValues] 

for id in ('lin', 'log', 'polar', 'ribbon', 'wireframe', 'surface', 'bar', 'pie', 'gant'):
    Plotly.plot (
        document.getElementById (id),
        [{
            x: xValues,
            y: yValues
        }],
        {
            margin: {t: 0}
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your markup. Wrapped your graph divs with a `.wrapper` element for easier formatting. Inline block elements create some space on screen, you can prevent this simply using the CSS `float` property. Don't forget to clear float to prevent parent collapsing, like I've done in the updated code. I've also applied some negative margin to get rid of double border:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .clearfix:after {
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        height: 0;
        clear: both;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .wrapper{
        padding: 1px 0 0 1px;
    }
    .wrapper div {
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        margin-top: -1px;
        margin-left: -1px;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div id="lin"></div>
        <div id="log"></div>
        <div id="polar"></div>
        <div id="ribbon"></div>
        <div id="wireframe"></div>
        <div id="surface"></div>
        <div id="bar"></div>
        <div id="pie"></div>
        <div id="gant"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="__javascript__/plotly_demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can checkout this page to understand how `.clearfix` actually works - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-alignment.php

Comment: I've tried your HTML, but I still get double borders and the 10 px padding is ignored. What I am after is a single line border around each plot, as specified in the CSS.

Comment: Just copy and paste this code in a blank HTML file and view that page in browser. You'll understand what i'm trying to say.

Comment: That is just  what I did. I opened an empty file and copied your html into it. Then loaded it into the browser. The graphs are adjacent now, which I don't want, but still the border isn't a single line, but a box in a box for each graph. So it's ok if each graph has its own, separate border, rather than the borders being merged. But I'd like one single border per graph. Right now there's a thin outer border and an inner border of which the left and top side are 2px rather than one, creating a kind of shadow effect.